# How to determine the location of the deno script?

Tags: javascript, typescript, deno

Let's say I issue the following command:

```
deno run --allow-read /scripts/where-am-i.ts
```

What would need to be inside `where-am-i.ts` for it to output:

```
/scripts
```

I've tried:

```
console.log(Deno.cwd());
```

which prints the directory the script was called from (`/` in this example).

I have also tried:

```
console.log(Deno.execPath());
```

which prints the location of the deno binary (`~/.cargo/bin/deno` for me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some utilities from the [`std/path`](https://deno.land/std@0.138.0/path) module to determine the directory of a module, based on its [import meta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.meta):

`so-72156289.ts`:

```ts
import * as path from "https://deno.land/std@0.138.0/path/mod.ts";

function getModuleDir(importMeta: ImportMeta): string {
  return path.resolve(path.dirname(path.fromFileUrl(importMeta.url)));
}

const dir = getModuleDir(import.meta);
console.log(dir);
```

```
$ deno run /Users/deno/examples/so-72156289.ts
/Users/deno/examples
```